# Issue when casting from DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, linq

I use the following which is generated from MVC project (in method ActionResult Index),
Now I want to cast the following var property (config) to the model class which is the class in the DB that was generated from (config class) ,how should I do that ?

```
var config = from m in db.Config
             select m;
```

I try like this but Its not working

```
Config config2 = (Config)config;
```

also with

```
Config config = from m in db.Config
                select m;
```

The error is:

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Admin.Config.Admin>' to 'AdminS.Config.Admin'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var config = from m in db.Config
             select m;
```

Is returning an `IQueryable<Admin.Config.Admin>` not a Admin class.  You effectively have a collection, you can use `.FirstOrDefault()` which will return the first object (or null).

```
Config config2;
Config firstConfigItem = config.FirstOrDefault();

if (firstConfigItem != null) {
   config2 = firstConfigItem;
}
```

Note: You do not need to cast from `Config` to `Config` as that would make no sense, you are already dealing with the correct type.  The compiler is originally complaining about `IQueryable<Config>` to `Config`.

To get the list of objects you can call `.ToList()` you would have to iterate over each object in the collection and assign it accordingly, at present you only have 1 variable.

Comment: Assume that I want to get the list of the objects how should I do that?

Comment: @JeanTehhe: Then call `ToList` instead, and you'll get a `List<Config>`.